# How to add a child from a class to stage from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to add a child of `EnemySpawned` class upon a hitTest from `EnemySpawn` to the main timeline.
class.

```
if(this.hitTestPoint(whatever))
                {
                    var spawn1:EnemySpawned = new EnemySpawned;
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);// functions inside the class
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);//
                    spawn1.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*((this.x - 300)- (this.x + 300) +1))+ this.x -300; spawn1.y = this.y;// +300;
                    MovieClip(root).addChild(spawn1);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

I've tried multiple sintaxes instead of `MovieClip(root).addChild(spawn1);`, nothing worked when the hit happened. I've imported the classes also.

Could anyone help a bit? thanks!

Comment: Try to use `stage.addChild(spawn1);`

Comment: `stage` and the Flash Pro "stage" are not the same thing. `MovieClip(root)` is the correct equivalent of the Flash Pro stage. I don't think your problem is adding to the stage -- the code you've posted is fine -- it's something related to your hit detection. Post your hit detection code.